# How to add location-pin to Cartagen map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, rendering

I don't see much mention of Cartagen on stackoverflow, so please point me somewhere else if there is a better forum for this question.  I am using Cartagen JavaScript library to render a map in the browser.  I want to place a location pin on the map.  I figure there must be an easy way to do this but I haven't been able to find it in the documentation or code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to place a map-pin.  I used User.set_loc() to set the location of the default User.  Then I used User.mark() to mark that location.  I changed the code in User.mark() from drawing a circle for the mark, to using ctx.drawImage() to put my .png of a map-pin on to the map.  I might be able to make other pins if I make other instances of User.

This use of User.mark() did not create an object that will be automatically be used on every redraw of the map.  For that I think I might have to use something like the User.add_node() and User.toggle_way_drawing() whereby a node is created, tagged with "user_submited", and put on the Geohash.objects array.  The Geohash.objects array is used by Gartagen.draw() to add user-submitted objects to the Cartagen.feature_queue which are then rendered on the map.

But I haven't totally figured out the use of User.add_node() yet, so instead I added code to Cartagen.draw() to call User.set_loc() and User.mark() every time the map map is redrawn.